# Best way to write REST API for sorting and pagination

Tags: java, rest, sorting, pagination

I'm writing a REST API to filter data along with sorting and pagination. Please see below two ways to pass values and help me on **" which one is better in below two ways and why?"**

```
1. Passing everything through @Requestbody
{
  "pageNumber": "1",
  "pageSize": "10",
  "sortField": "<fieldName>",
  "sortOrder": "ASC/DESC",
  "filters": {
    "<fieldName1>": "<enteredOrSelectedValue1>",
    "<fieldName2>": "<enteredOrSelectedValue2>"
  }
}

   
2. Passing sorting and pagination params through @RequestParam - pageNumber, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder and filters through @Requestbody
{
  "filters": {
    "<fieldName1>": "<enteredOrSelectedValue1>",
    "<fieldName2>": "<enteredOrSelectedValue2>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two answers, that happily lead the same place.

If you are thinking about sorting and pagination, then you are probably dealing with a request that has essentially read-only semantics.  That means that you want the method to be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).  Furthermore, you are clearly interested in getting data back, which means you need a method where we can expect a response-body

In other words, you want to use [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1).

One aspect of GET is that the request-body *has no defined semantics*.  That means, for example, that general-purpose intermediates (like a reverse proxy) aren't required to forward the request-body all the way through to your handler.

Therefore, if we want the sorting and paging parameters to make it all the way through to the server, they need to be part of the target-uri.

I would expect the elements in the target-uri to be available via RequestParam and the like, and not via RequestBody.

Second answer, same as the first: pages of data are often re-usable.  It can make sense to take pressure off of your server by sticking the pages in a general purpose cache.

Responses to requests are [cached](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) using the target-uri as the primary key (sometimes with additional header values as secondary keys).  The request-body is *not* part of the primary key; therefore you are going to want to prefer to have all of the information required encoded into the target-uri